# Iterate through the images and store each image as a list item

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Hi I have multiple images in a folder and I am iterating through them and converting them into 20x20 blocks. For each block in an image I am computing the mean value and this is done for each image. I want the result in a form of list of list which means if I have 6 images there should be 6 list items and for each list item there should be a 20x20 array having mean values of all the blocks.

```
img = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("resized/*.jpg")]
X=[]
for im in img:
    arr = np.asarray(im)
    arr = np.split(arr, 20)
    arr = np.array([np.split(x, 20, 1) for x in arr])
    mat = [arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(20) for j in range(20)]
    X.append(mat)
```

This is the desired output.

```
[[0,0.1,....,],[0,0.1,....,],[0,0.1,....,],[0,0.1,....,],[0,0.1,....,],[0,0.1,....,]]. Each item should be 400 values.
```

But right now I am getting only 400 values as result.

```
[[0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0,
 ....
  3.99,
  2.16,
  12.23,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  5.07,
  7.65,
 ....
  0.0,
  0.0,
  0.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension returns a list of single values. To create a 2d list try:

```
mat = [[arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(20)] for j in range(20)]
```

Comment: I want the result in the form of ```[[a11,a12,..,a120,a21,..a220,...a400400],[b11,b12,..,b120,b21,..b220,...b400400], [c11,c12,..,c120,c21,..c220,...c400400]]``` where a,b,c are the images in the folder "resized" and a11,b11,c11 are the blocks in the images a,b,c respectively

Answer (score 0):

The current code that I have is doing the desired output as I want. It was my bad that I didn't notice it before. The code is producing 6 list items with length of each list item equal to 400 which is the number of blocks in one image. Hence we have a 2d list of length 6 where each list item is a list of average values of each block.